# Proving a single function continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

I am supposed to check the following function for continuity:
$$h(x) = \frac {x^5}{x+5}$$

Knowing that the limits approaching from both sides have to be equal for the function to be continuous, I have no idea what to use for the left or the right side.

For example an exercise after this looks like this:

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}X/3, & x<=1\\ (x+1)^2 -11/3 & x>1\end{cases}$$

And I could solve it since I know X = 1 and had different functions for the limits on every side.

How should I approach this? I graphed it and it looks like continuous.

Comment: Your post is unlcear. Are you interested in the first function given or the second one ?

Comment: @Rebellos I thought it was quite clear that the second one is posted only as an example where Ario knows what to do, as opposed to the first one.

Comment: If it‘s not clear I am interested in the first one. I gave the second one simply as an example on why I am unable to complete it.

Comment: Well, one thing to do when you're stuck is to go back to the definitions. What is your _definition_ of "continuous"? Is (an appropriately formal rephrasing of)  "limits from both sides are equal" your actual definition, or do you have something else?

Comment: @Ario In your example you chose a specific point, $x=1$, but you could have been asked to check for continuity in a point other than $x=1$, right? It is the same in the first situation... You are not asked to check for continuity in a specific point, so you must discuss what happens in the whole domain.

Comment: @Ario The answer depends on what are allowed to use. Your function in a quotient of continuous functions (polynomials) so it will be continuous whenever the denominator is not zero, i.e. the while domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition :** A function is continuous in its domain if it is continuous in every point of it.

The function $h(x) = \frac{x^5}{x+5}$ is defined on $D_h = \mathbb R \setminus\{-5\}$, since the denominator must be different than zero. It involves the quotient (or multiplication to be more rigorous) of polynomial terms, which are continuous and thus $h(x)$ is continuous in $D_h$.

**The difference with the second one :** The second one is indeed continuous in every point of its branches, but in order to be globally continuous you need to check continuity at the specific point which the branch changes. If and only if it is continuous there, it will be continuous globally as the branches are continuous in their respective domains. This is done, as you correctly said, by the limits approach.

Comment: Am I not able to do the first one through the limits approach?

Comment: The formal definition of continuity for a point in the domain of $f$ is $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$. If you could check every single limit for all the points, then it would be useful via limit. But that's not possible, as the domain has infinite points. This means that a limits approach isn't suitable for the specific example.